# Sort by updatedAt field in sails-dynamodb

Tags: node.js, sails.js, amazon-dynamodb

I want to sort found elements by updatedAt field which is created and updated by default.

I have the following code:

Model:

```
  module.exports = {
      attributes: {
         id:{
            type: "string",
            primaryKey: 'hash'
         },
        title:{
            type: "string",
            required: true
        },
        category:{
            type: "string",
            required: true
        },
        subCategory:{
            type: "string"
        },
   }
```

Controller:

```
 Anuncio.find({
        where: {
            category: request.category,
            subCategory: request.subCategory
        },
        sort: "1"
    }).exec((err, result) => {
        if (err) return next(err);

        return res.json(result);
    });
```

I know that this code need an index for sort by I have no idea how do it.

I am using sails-dynamodb adapter.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Anuncio.find({
    where: {
        category: request.category,
        subCategory: request.subCategory
    },
    sort: 'updatedAt DESC'
}).exec((err, result) => {
    if (err) return next(err);

    return res.json(result);
});
```

Comment: The problem is that Sails-dynamodb adaptor works with index for sort, so that solution don't work for me.